# Return first 10 key values for hash

Tags: ruby

I am reading a JSON like this:

```
[
  {
    "Low": 8.63,
    "Volume": 14211900,
    "Date": "2012-10-26",
    "High": 8.79,
    "Close": 8.65,
    "Adj Close": 8.65,
    "Open": 8.7
  },
  {
    "Low": 8.65,
    "Volume": 12167500,
    "Date": "2012-10-25",
    "High": 8.81,
    "Close": 8.73,
    "Adj Close": 8.73,
    "Open": 8.76
  },
  {
    "Low": 8.68,
    "Volume": 20239700,
    "Date": "2012-10-24",
    "High": 8.92,
    "Close": 8.7,
    "Adj Close": 8.7,
    "Open": 8.85
  },
  {
    "Low": 8.78,
    "Volume": 23433900,
    "Date": "2012-10-23",
    "High": 8.94,
    "Close": 8.78,
    "Adj Close": 8.78,
    "Open": 8.93
  }
]
```

Using this:

```
json = File.read("#{symbols[0]}.json")
```

Then doing this:

```
result = JSON.parse(json)
```

Then, when I want to select the first value for the key value "Low", I did this:

```
puts result[0]['Low']
```

This returned 58.75 (correct).

**But I want to get the first three values for "Low". I tried doing the following, but it doesn't work (says can't convert string to integer). Why?**

```
puts result[0..2]['Low']
```

Comment: What you posted is neither a hash nor an array. What exactly do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
results = [
  {"Low"=>58.75, "Volume"=>163200, "Date"=>"1962-02-01", "High"=>59.63, "Close"=>59.38, "Adj Close"=>0.61, "Open"=>59.63},
  {"Low"=>59.63, "Volume"=>134400, "Date"=>"1962-01-31", "High"=>60.0, "Close"=>59.75, "Adj Close"=>0.62, "Open"=>59.88},
  {"Low"=>59.13, "Volume"=>91200, "Date"=>"1962-01-26", "High"=>59.38, "Close"=>59.38, "Adj Close"=>0.61, "Open"=>59.13},
  {"Low"=>59.13, "Volume"=>91200, "Date"=>"1962-01-25", "High"=>59.88, "Close"=>59.13, "Adj Close"=>0.61, "Open"=>59.75},
  {"Low"=>58.5, "Volume"=>110400, "Date"=>"1962-01-24", "High"=>60.13, "Close"=>59.75, "Adj Close"=>0.62, "Open"=>60.13}
]
results[0..2].collect {|element| element['Low']}
>> [58.75, 59.63, 59.13]
```

Comment: what's better different between the two?  Eventually, I want to be able to calculate moving averages (will be using the simple statistics gem, though I know there are various ruby ways).  So will be requiring something like (if you are at [0], add up [0..9] and divide by 10 - then add key ('10 Day SMA') and value, then go to [1], add up [1..10] and divide by 10, etc, etc.)

Comment: I prefer this. Sergio's way works fine but I think using `map` or `collect` directly on your subarray is a bit more Rubyish than doing it with indexes (which is a little more like the `for` loop you might use to do the same thing in other languages). For moving averages, you might want to take a look at the `each_cons` function [in the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons)... `results.each_cons(10) {|items| calculate average... }`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have array of hashes, you can do this:

```
results = [
  {"Low"=>58.75, "Volume"=>163200, "Date"=>"1962-02-01", "High"=>59.63, "Close"=>59.38, "Adj Close"=>0.61, "Open"=>59.63},
  {"Low"=>59.63, "Volume"=>134400, "Date"=>"1962-01-31", "High"=>60.0, "Close"=>59.75, "Adj Close"=>0.62, "Open"=>59.88},
  {"Low"=>59.13, "Volume"=>91200, "Date"=>"1962-01-26", "High"=>59.38, "Close"=>59.38, "Adj Close"=>0.61, "Open"=>59.13},
  {"Low"=>59.13, "Volume"=>91200, "Date"=>"1962-01-25", "High"=>59.88, "Close"=>59.13, "Adj Close"=>0.61, "Open"=>59.75},
  {"Low"=>58.5, "Volume"=>110400, "Date"=>"1962-01-24", "High"=>60.13, "Close"=>59.75, "Adj Close"=>0.62, "Open"=>60.13}
]

(0..2).map {|idx| results[idx]['Low']} # => [58.75, 59.63, 59.13]
```

Comment: Thanks again Sergio, I could sure use you as a tutor!

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is that

- `results[0]` returns a single hash (which you can then index with a string `['key']`)
- `results[0..2]` returns another (smaller) array of hashes (which you need to index with an integer to get a single hash).

Using the `map` function ([docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map)) allows you to get the values you're after. Note that it's aliased to `collect` so you can use whatever you prefer. In this case you are collecting a set of values so that might be the best conceptual fit.

```
results[0..2].map {|hash| hash['Low']}
# or equivalently
results[0..2].collect {|hash| hash['Low']}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Andy, I appreciate the explanation